# Serilog: Can't get .LogTrace to display?

Tags: c#, serilog

Can't get calls to .LogTrace to display on console screen, **I've tried** (bold, read before answering) various appsettings.json setups, Verbose, Trace, All, along with parent node names of MinimumLogLevel and LogLevel, sat there for 30 minutes but it doesn't seem to be having any of it?

Serilog Setup:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .ReadFrom.Configuration(configRoot)
                .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                .WriteTo.Console(
                    outputTemplate: "{Timestamp:dd-MM} at {Timestamp:HH:mm:ss.fff} - {Level:u5} - {Message}{NewLine:l}{Exception:l}", 
                    theme: SerilogThemes.CustomLightTerminal
                )
                .CreateLogger();
```

appsettings.json:

```
"Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Trace"
    }
},
```

Calls to .Log* methods display everything up from Information

Comment: Serilog Sinks have a minimum level fiter; you likely need to do `.Console(minimumLevel: Trace`. Also in case the file based config is not being applied, doing `.MinimumLevel.Trace` in the config code will definitely work (but remove it after you've proven that's not the problem).

Comment: I don't see a log level for `Trace`, I do see `Verbose`.